# Efficiently delete from one table where ID matches another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-delete, postgresql-performance

I have two tables with few million records in a PostgreSQL database.
I'm trying to delete rows from one table where ID matches ID of another table. I have used the following command:

```
delete from table1 where id in (select id from table2)
```

The above command has been taking lot of time (few hours) which got me wondering is there a faster way to do this operation. Will creating indices help?

I have also tried the delete using join as suggested by few people:

```
delete from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

But the above command returned a syntax error. Can this be modified to avoid the error?

Comment: Did you try an `exists`  condition instead of the `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Syntax

You second attempt is not legal syntax for [`DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) in PostgreSQL. This is legal:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1 t1
USING  table2 t2
WHERE  t2.id = t1.id;
```

Consider [*"Notes"* for the `DELETE` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html#id-1.9.3.100.8):

> PostgreSQL lets you reference columns of other tables in the `WHERE` condition by specifying the other tables in the `USING` clause. For example,
> [...]
> This syntax is not standard.
> [...]
> In some cases the join style is easier to write or faster to execute than the sub-select style.

#### Index

> Will creating indices help?

The usefulness of indexes always depends on the complete situation. If `table1` is big, and much bigger than `table2`, an index on `table1.id` should typically help. Typically, `id` would be your `PRIMARY KEY`, which is indexed implicitly anyway ...
Also typically, an index on `table2` would not help (and not be used even if it exists.)

But like I said: Depends on the complete situation, and you disclosed preciously little.

Other details of your setup might make the deletes expensive. FK constraints, triggers, indexes, locks held by concurrent transactions, table and index bloat ...

Or non-unique rows in `table2`. (But I would assume `ìd` to be unique?) Then you would first extract a unique set of IDs from `table2`. Depending on cardinalities, a simple `DISTINCT` or more sophisticated query techniques would be in order ...

Comment: ... probably worth mentioning that this will NOT work if you have a foreign key relation that isn't `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Foreign key constraints constrain writes that would violate referential integrity. But no constraints were mentioned for this.